# Limiting size of hierarchical data for reproducible example

Tags: r, dataset, reproducible-research

I am trying to come up with *reproducible example (RE)* for this question: [Errors related to data frame columns during merging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25101444/data-frame-columns-lost-after-merging). To be qualified as having a RE, the question lacks only *reproducible data*. However, when I tried to use pretty much standard approach of `dput(head(myDataObj))`, the output produced is 14MB size file. The problem is that my data object is a *list of data frames*, so `head()` limitation doesn't appear to work **recursively**.

I haven't found any options for `dput()` and `head()` functions that would allow me to control data size recursively for *complex objects*. Unless I am wrong on the above, what other **approaches** to creating a minimal *RE dataset* would you recommend me in this situation?

Comment: Does it only not work for certain data values? Can you just create simulated data with something like `replicate(5, data.frame(x=1:10, y=cumsum(runif(10))), simplify=F)`?

Comment: Or you can take the head of each of the data.frames in the list first `dput(lapply(myDataObj, head))` but it sounds like that will still be large.

Comment: @MrFlick: Appreciate your fast feedback! I will try to use both of your recommendations and report back. However, creating a simulated data versus real data might not help in building a RE, but, on the other hand, might expose the fact that the data is the reason of the experienced issues.

Comment: @MrFlick: Your `dput(lapply(myDataObj, head))` advice seems to have worked perfectly. Thanks again! Would appreciate, if you could give feedback on my original question, referenced above.

Comment: The other option is to dissect the problem first. In many cases, the actual problem is part of a bigger setting, but the bigger setting isn't necessary to solve the particular problem. Without extra information it's difficult to give more concrete advice obviously

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Along the lines of @MrFlick's comment of using `lapply`, you may use any of the `apply` family of functions to perform the `head` or `sample` functions depending on your needs in order to reduce the size for both *RE*s and for testing purposes (I've found that working with subsets or subsamples of large sets of data is preferable for debugging and even charting).

It should be noted that `head` and `tail` provide the first or last bits of a structure, but sometimes these don't have sufficient variance in them for RE purposes, and are certainly not random, which is where `sample` may become more useful.

Suppose we have a hierarchical tree structure (list of lists of...) and we want to subset each "leaf" while preserving the structure and labels in the tree.

```
x <- list( 
    a=1:10, 
    b=list( ba=1:10, bb=1:10 ), 
    c=list( ca=list( caa=1:10, cab=letters[1:10], cac="hello" ), cb=toupper( letters[1:10] ) ) )
```

*NOTE: In the following, I actually can't tell the difference between using `how="replace"` and `how="list"`.*

*ALSO NOTE: This won't be great for `data.frame` leaf nodes.*

```
# Set seed so the example is reproducible with randomized methods:
set.seed(1)
```

You can use the default `head` in a recursive apply in this way:

```
rapply( x, head, how="replace" )
```

Or pass an anonymous function that modifies the behavior:

```
# Complete anonymous function
rapply( x, function(y){ head(y,2) }, how="replace" )
# Same behavior, but using the rapply "..." argument to pass the n=2 to head.
rapply( x, head, how="replace", n=2 )
```

The following gets a randomized `sample` ordering of each leaf:

```
# This works because we use minimum in case leaves are shorter
# than the requested maximum length.
rapply( x, function(y){ sample(y, size=min(length(y),2) ) }, how="replace" )

# Less efficient, but maybe easier to read:
rapply( x, function(y){ head(sample(y)) }, how="replace" )
```

---

```
# XXX: Does NOT work The following does **not** work 
# because `sample` with a `size` greater than the 
# item being sampled does not work (when 
# sampling without replacement)
rapply( x, function(y){ sample(y, size=2) }, how="replace" )
```

Comment: +1 and accepted. Wow - I've had this issue quite a while ago. @MrFlick's comment was enough to solve my problem at the time. However, I appreciate your answer and some details that go beyond his advice.

Comment: Saying "any of the apply functions will be suitable" is likely to be incorrect since `apply`-itself will always coerce its inputs to atomic vectors.